# What is the source of the legal stigma to returning items to shops for refunds to different cards than were used to buy them?

Tags: england-and-wales, retail

A consumer purchased an item from a ship using a bank card as payment. Almost all shops when processing returns will at least make a token gesture or pretence of ensuring that the card which is presented for receiving a refund is the same that appears in the record of purchase, heavily suggesting that there is a statutory requirement for them to do so. But what are the laws which are concerned with such a scenario, and do any of them stigmatise a consumer’s either inadvertently or deliberately frustrating these checks, however rigorous or tokenistic they may be?

Comment: It's not necessarily a legal requirement, but far more likely to be a technical/resolution requirement.  For instance, despite the fact that you can usually present the card for payment and leave immediately, your bank may not actually be informed of the charges until later.  In such a case, the money hasn't made it to the store, and so what they will do instead is _roll back_ (cancel) the transaction.  If you could refund to another card, then this could be exploited to steal money from the store.

Comment: I think it could be related to anti money laundering regulations.

Comment: It's more likely (but I'm not in a position to check) to be card provider's/processor's regulations. Possibly to prevent avoidance of cash advance fees (charge to credit card; refund to cash or debit card) and possibly exploitation of cashback/points reward schemes.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in comments already, this is not a statutory requirement, but a policy associated with the use of payment cards.

The policy may be that of the individual retailer, or it may be that of the banks in general, but the essential issue at stake is to prevent customers converting card charges directly into raw cash through the charade of buying and then returning goods.

This is firstly because the card system is otherwise so riddled with holes for fraudulence that there has to be careful traceability and accounting as a backstop to misuse, but also secondly the amount of fraud is still so great that the losses are seriously mitigated by ensuring that only the marginal cost of goods or services is lost when fraud occurs, not the full sale price (refunded in cash).

Controlling what consumers with credit cards spend their money on is also important, since people often have instant access to credit facilities, and banks monitor and control these things as much as possible to control credit risk.

Allowing conversion of these credit facilities directly to cash, breaks the monitoring of the system, and enables the customer to use money extended by the bank on credit to transact with those whom the banks wouldn't permit a direct transaction - like illegal gamblers, or drug dealers.

Answer (score 4):

> what are the laws which are concerned with such a scenario, and do any of them stigmatise a consumer’s either inadvertently or deliberately frustrating these checks

There are no laws that require credit card refunds to be returned to the same card.

Where such rules exist, they are imposed by the payment processors, acquiring banks and sometimes the merchants themselves.

The reasons are:

1. When the original payment is made, the merchant does not get 100% of it: the banks (both the acquiring and the issuing) and payment processors receive a small percentage as their fee. So, if the transaction is reversed/refunded, all those fees need to roll back. This is straightforward when refunding to the same card (and a headache to get right if refunding to another card).
2. Fraud mitigation: the consumer could use a stolen credit card for the original purchase (with PIN unknown), but seek to refund to a different card for which they know the PIN, from which they could then withdraw cash from an ATM.

Comment: Though one could easily imagine national laws existing to the effect of mandating such fraud prevention measures in the interests of combating such financial crime/fraud.